# How 7zip generates hash for multiple files?

Tags: 7-zip, hashing

I have a zero size file.
7-zip generates `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` for it. It's fine.

But if I select 2 zero size files, 7zip generates `b47346ddbdd6961a64aa7edf2bc130205fb10f12` for them.
How this was?

It tried `SHA1(SHA1(file1) + SHA1(file2))` algorithm, but the result is other: `43b1e995dbead10e335145327cf24f8d0ec38f88`.

Comment: I want to write a program that would be able to generate the same result. So that I need to know the algorithm to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a quick Python test, but if you are trying to recreate the exact algorithm used then you would be better off looking at the 7zip source code.

Answer (score 3):

From [7zip: h (Hash) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/hash.htm)

> #### Notes
>
> 7-Zip shows hash values for each file, the sum of hash values and the sum that includes all hash values of data and all hash values for filenames.

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' h -scrcsha1 .\new*

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning
2 files, 0 bytes

SHA1                                              Size  Name
---------------------------------------- -------------  ------------
DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709             0  New Text Document (2).txt
DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709             0  New Text Document.txt
---------------------------------------- -------------  ------------
B47346DDBDD6961A64AA7EDF2BC130205FB10F12             0

Files: 2
Size: 0

SHA1   for data:              B47346DDBDD6961A64AA7EDF2BC130205FB10F12
SHA1   for data and names:    AFF4696D47DF1F0699A236DD70D5D51B960DD360

Everything is Ok
```

The individual file data for two zero byte files is indeed the same, but two zero byte files concatenated together is not necessarily the same as one single byte file. 7zip might internally represent that as an [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) byte for each file and no actual data.

Doing a quick test in Python:

```
>>> a = 0xDA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
>>> b = 0xDA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
>>> c = a + b
>>> hex(c)
'0x1b47347dcbcd6961a64ab7fdf2ac031215fb00e12'
>>>
```

The difference is

> 0x**0**b4734**6**d**d**b**d**d6961a64a**a**7**e**df2**b**c**1**3**0**2**0**5fb**1**0**f**12
> 0x**1**b4734**7**d**c**b**c**d6961a64a**b**7**f**df2**a**c**0**3**1**2**1**5fb**0**0**e**12

Which means it is not a simple addition, there is something else going on.

If you want the precise details of how the data is handled then the source code for 7-zip is [here.](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip/tree/master/C)

Comment: Yeah, it seems it's a kind of summing of bytes on the same index. `print("".join(map(lambda x: hex(int(x, 16) * 2 % 256)[-2:], "da 39 a3 ee 5e 6b 4b 0d 32 55 bf ef 95 60 18 90 af d8 07 09".split())).replace("x", "0"))` produces `b47246dcbcd6961a64aa7ede2ac030205eb00e12`. Not the same, but more the similar result. Need to investigate the case of the sum is over 255. (I just double the value, since both hashes are the same in this example

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mokubai's answer I figure out how it works.

It's a sum of appropriate bytes on the same index in hash arrays.
In case of a sum is over `255` the follow sum (if exists) is increased by `1`.

Here s JS code:

```js
/** @param {...(Buffer|Uint8Array)} arrays
 *  @return {Uint8Array}  */
function zipByteArrays(...arrays) {
    const result = _zipByteArrays(arrays[0], arrays[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        _zipByteArrays(result, arrays[i], result);
    }
    return result;
}

function _zipByteArrays(a, b, result = new Uint8Array(a.length)) {
    let extra = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        const sum = a[i] + b[i] + extra;
        result[i] = sum % 256;
        if (sum > 255) {
            extra = 1;
        } else {
            extra = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The additional demo code:

```js
import crypto from "node:crypto";

// Empty file hash
const hash1 = Buffer.from("b47246dcbcd6961a64aa7ede2ac030205eb00e12", "hex");

console.log(hex(zipByteArrays(hash1, hash1))                      === "b47346ddbdd6961a64aa7edf2bc130205fb10f12");
console.log(hex(zipByteArrays(hash1, hash1, hash1))               === "8eade9cb1c42e22796ff3dcfc12149b00e8a171b");
console.log(hex(zipByteArrays(hash1, hash1, hash1, hash1))        === "68e78cba7bad2d35c854fdbe57826140be621f24");
console.log(hex(zipByteArrays(hash1, hash1, hash1, hash1, hash1)) === "422130a9da187942faa9bcaeede279d06d3b272d");

function hex(array) {
    return Buffer.from(array).toString("hex")
}

function sha1(value) {
    const hasher = crypto.createHash("sha1");
    hasher.update(value);
    return hasher.digest();
}
```

---

However, the other question is how 7-zip works when it creates hashes "for data and names"?

For example,

```js
const f1_name = sha1("file1.txt");
const f2_name = sha1("file2.txt");
console.log(hex(zipByteArrays(hash1, f1_name, hash1, f2_name)));
```

prints `447d1e8e010c7344dfa2be63c7ab561b8de1d186` while the expected hash for 2 empty files with `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` names is `5d0543836f28cd8c93975c90c61373cd30c9c73f`